# How to stop matlab stairs command from dropping last element?

Tags: matlab

```
stairs(1:10)
```

gives this plot:
[image]

If you're not careful, you'll miss the last data point.  Obviously, you can fix this, this way:

```
stairs([1:10 10])
```

But seriously?  That strikes me as just silly.  I see no obvious "easy" workaround, other than rolling my own stairs function.

```
mystairs = @(x)stairs([x x(end)])
```

But that doesn't really generalize stairs, just fixes it for one (very limited) use case.  I could go through all the work of creating a .m file, and handing var args correctly etc.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: The documentation is clear that if you supply a vector, then range is `1:length(x)`. If you have an array x, just supply `x([1:end end],:)` being careful to keep vectors in column format.

Answer (score 0):

That's sort of the nature of the graph: the data points represent observations or value transitions, and you've got one transition at the very last observation point. And it's the general contract of Matlab plots that the final data point is at the very end of the line graph. The issue with doing `[x x(end)]` is that now you're graphing an additional bogus data point, and the line will be extended from 10 to 11 on the independent variable X axis, which is outside the range covered by the data points. Might be misleading, especially if some other code grabs the Y data back out of the figure handle and does something with it.

How about increasing the `xlim` of the plot so the final state transition line doesn't fall right on the edge of the graph and get obscured by the border?

Comment: `xlim` doesn't solve the problem.  Change my example to `stairs([0 1 2 1])`, `hold all`, `stairs([0 1 2 0])`.  In this joint plot you cannot tell the value of the 4th element of the first data set at all.